# what to test for a client class that calls 3rd party api in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how to test functions that makes a http call to apis and get json response back. what are things to consider to test ? , if one can't make actual call to outside apis from the test method.

```
class Client
  include HTTParty 
  base_uri "https://www.somesite.com"
  format :json

  def send
    begin 
      response = HTTParty.get(url)
      if response.successful?
        response 
      else
        raise 'invalid response'
      end
    rescue HTTParty::Error => e 
      logger.warn(e.message)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) gem. 
As from description this gem allows to record your test suite's HTTP interactions and replay them during future test runs for fast, deterministic, accurate tests. 
From my point of view I would record 2 cases for your API, one for success respond and second for failed respond and checked that they are covered by your code and you do not receive unexpected result.